# How do I use icons from Flaticon in my html?

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I want to give my website some icons. Now I see that many people use this website Flaticon.

What I have done is put something like this in my CSS:

```
/**    
 * Font 1    
 */    
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon1";
  src: url("flaticon1.eot");
  src: url("flaticon1.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("flaticon1.woff") format("woff"), url("flaticon1.ttf") format("truetype"), url("flaticon1.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="flaticon1-"]:before,
[class*=" flaticon1-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon1-"]:after,
[class*=" flaticon1-"]:after {
  font-family: "Flaticon1";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.flaticon1-basic21:before {
  content: "\e000";
}

.flaticon1-bicycle21:before {
  content: "\e001";
}

.flaticon1-car6:before {
  content: "\e002";
}


/**    
 * Font 2    
 */    
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon2";
  src: url("flaticon2.eot");
  src: url("flaticon2.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("flaticon2.woff") format("woff"), url("flaticon2.ttf") format("truetype"), url("flaticon2.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="flaticon2-"]:before,
[class*=" flaticon2-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon2-"]:after,
[class*=" flaticon2-"]:after {
  font-family: "Flaticon2";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.flaticon2-basic21:before {
  content: "\e000";
}

.flaticon2-bicycle21:before {
  content: "\e001";
}

.flaticon2-car6:before {
  content: "\e002";
}
```

http://support.flaticon.com/hc/en-us/articles/205019862-CSS-code-for-Iconfont-

I downloaded the wanted icon but it doesn't display the icon. It displays this:

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You probably didn't include the font file(s) properly in your project. Do you see an errors in the console? What you have for `url()` in your CSS expects the icon font file to be in the same folder as the CSS file.

Comment: @hungerstar You're right, what the console says is that it failed to load the resource (ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). I do have icon font file it in the same folder. Does that mean that I named it improperly?

Comment: Possibly. Does the filename in `url()` match your CSS? Are you possibly missing one of the font file types? You usually need to have more than one type, i.e. `tff`, `woff`, `svg`, to work with most browsers. Perhaps you're missing one and that's where the error is.

Comment: @hungerstar I was downloading svg files, the others that I can choose from are png, eps, psd and </>base 64. if I want to get ttf and woff files, do I have to convert or is this a different type of format?

Comment: What you downloaded are not font files. Those file formats will allow you to use the icons as an image. I'm not sure why they have that CSS `@font-face` example as they don't provide font files. Out of the formats they do provide, _"PNG, SVG, EPS, PSD and BASE 64 formats,"_ base 64 is the only format that you could use to include it as a font.

Comment: @hungerstar Hey, I solved the problem. Apparently you have to put icons in your collection to be able to download them as Iconfont or SVG sprite. Quite weird that they have no guide or tutorial on it. There is one more thing I'd like to ask. The icons appear smaller than I wanted them to be. How do I make them bigger(for example the size of the div they're in)

Comment: That is odd. Glad you figured it out. You might want to add that as an answer even though you'd be answering your own question. Someone else might have a similar issue with Flaticon.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how do I mark my comment as accepted? Also, how do I make icons bigger?

Comment: You'll actually have to answer your question. Then you can mark it accepted (might have to wait **X** amount of time). As far as the size that is another question.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Prepare your collection**

Add monocolor icons to the collection for your website

**2. Download iconfont**

Open your collection and press the Download collection button, then select Iconfont

**3. Prepare your collection**

Copy the source files and CSS to your web folder.

**4. Load the stylesheet**

Request the CSS stylesheet from the head of your web.

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_website_domain/css_root/flaticon.css" >
```

**5. Use the classes**

Use the `classes` of each icon and they will appear on your website. After, manipulate them with `CSS`.
Use example:

```
<i class="flaticon-airplane49"></i> or <span class="flaticon-airplane49"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I downloaded file formats, not font files. I was only able to download icons as either Iconfont or SVG sprite after I have put icons in my collection. It downloads the whole collection of course.

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.flaticon.com/iconfonts

Answer (score 0):

Just download the icon and put this in the head: 
`<link rel="icon" href="resources/filename"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the flaticon.css file in your server (and the other 5 or 6).

Then check which items are available there.

.flaticon-bath:before { content: "\f122"; }

And then you just use the class.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the size...

```
font-family: Flaticon;
    font-size: 50px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can change the font size, just paste the below code in your css file and that's it.

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before, [class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {

font-size: 150px;

}
```