# Flaticons not showing up on WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

I have almost finished converting an HTML website over to WordPress but I couldn't something to work. I am just creating a new theme to switch the website over. [Here is the link to see what it should look like](https://zekemaurer.com/rokstar/), There are three icons that are not showing up, right under the about section. And here is the link to my site, [zekemaurer.com](https://zekemaurer.com/).

Here is the code.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="single-service txt2_is_show">
                        <div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-web-design"></span></div>
                        <div class="srvc-content">
                            <h4>Realtor</h4>
                            <p>I ought to just try that with my boss; I'd get kicked out on the spot. But who knows, maybe that would be the best</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="single-service txt2_is_show">
                        <div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-settings"></span></div>
                        <div class="srvc-content">
                            <h4>Investor</h4>
                            <p>I ought to just try that with my boss; I'd get kicked out on the spot. But who knows, maybe that would be the best</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How do I get the icons to show up on my wordpress website?

Comment: Do you mean the flaticons?

Comment: Yes, I meant the flations

Comment: Does this answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46660289/13088403

Comment: I bought a HTML website and everything works, but im switching it over to wordpress. Its not showing up on my wordpress site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `assets/css/flaticon.css` from the example website.

Specifically, this CSS which you can probably dump onto the end of `style.css`

```
/*

    Flaticon icon font: Flaticon
    Creation date: 23/10/2017 08:34
    */

@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("../fonts/Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("../fonts/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("../fonts/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../fonts/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  }
}

[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
    font-family: Flaticon;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.flaticon-play-button:before { content: "\f100"; }
.flaticon-adobe:before { content: "\f101"; }
.flaticon-settings:before { content: "\f102"; }
.flaticon-web-design:before { content: "\f103"; }
```

Comment: This exact same code is already within the flaticon.css file.

Comment: The problem was i didn't have the assets/css/flaticon.css. Thanks!